# airflow startup failed due to gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn, airflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python_runtime/bin/airflow", line 15, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/admin/airflow/python_runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 423, in webserver
    'gunicorn', run_args
  File "/home/admin/airflow/python_runtime/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 346, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)
  File "/home/admin/airflow/python_runtime/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 385, in _execvpe
    func(fullname, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I find out that this error was cause by no gunicorn avaiable,so I print all paths in os.py:

```
/home/admin/airflow/python_runtime/bin/gunicorn
/home/admin/python2.7.2/bin/gunicorn
/home/admin/tools/local/bin/gunicorn
/home/admin/tools/bin/gunicorn
/home/admin/tools/opsdb/gunicorn
/home/admin/odps_tools/dship/gunicorn
/home/admin/php/bin/gunicorn
/home/admin/cmake/bin/gunicorn
/home/admin/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/gunicorn
/home/admin/tools/bin/gunicorn
/usr/kerberos/bin/gunicorn
/usr/local/sbin/gunicorn
/usr/sbin/gunicorn
/sbin/gunicorn
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn
/bin/gunicorn
/usr/bin/gunicorn
/usr/X11R6/bin/gunicorn
```

while gunicorn exist in this path

```
/home/admin/airflow/python_runtime/bin/gunicorn
```

something wrong with my env?

Answer (score 13):

Airflow seems to expect gunicorn in PATH. For my ubuntu instance this fixed it:

`$ export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
$ airflow webserver`

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: As I said in the answer, add gunicorns path to your $PATH.

Comment: For me guinicorn (as well as the Airflow service) is located here on AWS EC2-Instance (Amazon Linux 1): `/usr/local/bin/airflow` or `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn` so for example I say `sudo -E /usr/local/bin/airflow webserver` when I want to run Airflow (the -E loads the environment variables for sudo).

Comment: FYI adding guinicorn to my path did not fix the issue for me. I can type `gunicorn` in on my terminal and the service is found so it's definitely on the path.

Comment: Does not work for me as well. I found a proper solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352998/airflow-systemd-fails-due-to-gunicorn

Comment: fixed for me by running `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` instead

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS, it wasn't enough with the proposed solution. If I used relative path (with either `~` or `$HOME`) it didn't work, but using absolute path solved the issue: `PATH="${PATH}:/path/to/.venv/bin"`
As you can see, I'm using a hidden folder that I created with Python venv, maybe this is connected.

To test it, is not enough to run `gunicorn` alone, this worked to me with the relative path as well, but `which gunicorn` returned nothing, and this indicates that `airflow webserver` will fail to start.

Comment: This solution seem strange, but worked for me too :-)